# Problem with the output of a function with postgresql

Tags: function, psql

I have a table named 'reserves' and the exercise asks me to make a function that counts how many reservations are with an id lower than the id I give as the only parameter of the function. They also ask me that when I introduce 'NULL' as a parameter, the function must make a sum of all of the imports from the column 'import' and show the total. I have half of the function working. The 'NULL' part is the one not working.

Now I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compta_reserves(int) RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE
num_reserves INT:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mobilitat.reserves);
id ALIAS FOR $1;
comptador INT:=0;
i INT:=1;
import_total double precision:=((SELECT SUM(import) FROM mobilitat.reserves WHERE import<60)::INT);

BEGIN
IF (id=NULL) THEN
      RETURN import_total AS int;
ELSE
      WHILE i<num_reserves LOOP
         IF (SELECT id_reserva FROM mobilitat.reserves WHERE id_reserva=i)<id  THEN
        IF (SELECT import FROM mobilitat.reserves WHERE id_reserva=i)<60 THEN
                comptador=comptador+1;
            END IF;
     END IF;
         i=i+1;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN comptador;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

When I run the function with the 'NULL' parameter, I just get an empty table with no sum.